# How to redirect named route with query string?

Tags: laravel, url, redirect

I've got the below code which is working well as expected but I'd like to redirect to the route with a query string whereby `condition=$vehicle->condition&make={{$vehicle->make}}&model={{$vehicle->model}}`

```
   public function update()
  

      {
            //I've removed the logic for simplicity
            
            return redirect(route('vehicles.show', $vehicle))->with('flash', 
           'Vehicle Edited Successfully');
      }
```

Tried some solutions and some link linking to documentation but couldn't still get it to work. Any assistance will be highly appreciated, cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second parameter to the `route()` helper is the parameter list. Any parameters passed in that aren't defined in the route itself will get appended to the url as query string parameters.

Your code would look something like:

```
return redirect(route('vehicles.show', [
    $vehicle,
    'condition' => $vehicle->condition,
    'make' => $vehicle->make,
    'model' => $vehicle->model
]))->with('flash', 'Vehicle Edited Successfully');
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer and the other one provided here solve my problem. Is there any advantage over the other or it's just a matter of preference?

Comment: @AlphyGacheru This method will automatically encode the query parameters. So, for example, if the condition had an ampersand in it, this method would encode it, whereas plain string concatenation wouldn't. I think it's a bit cleaner. Additionally, if you ever moved these into route parameters, your code wouldn't need to change at all, but that is a small likelyhood.

Answer (score 1):

Try to concat the query params in the redirect method

```php
return redirect(
    route('vehicles.show', $vehicle) . 
    "?condition={$vehicle->condition}&make={$vehicle->make}&model={$vehicle->model}"
)
->with('flash', 'Vehicle Edited Successfully');
```

More safe way when concatenating query string params would be to use `http_build_query()` function as pointed out in the comments by @patricus

```php
$queryString = http_build_query([
    'condition' => $vehicle->condition,
    'make' => $vehicle->make,
    'model' => $vehicle->model
]);

return redirect(route('vehicles.show') . "?{$queryString}")
    ->with('flash', 'Vehicle Edited Successfully');
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer and the other one provided here solve my problem. Is there any advantage over the other or it's just a matter of preference?

Comment: Can't think of any advantage/disadvantage - however @patricus's answer is probably more Laravel(ish) way - honestly I wasn't aware that values passed as 2nd param to the route function will append to query string if not route params - I still like to keep it unambiguous that these are query string params so will stick to my version - for me it boils down to my own preference

Comment: @Donkarnash If you prefer to stick to this method, you may want to incorporate the `http_build_query()` function, so that your parameters will get urlencoded if needed. Imagine the `$vehicle->condition` parameter had an ampersand in it. Without encoding it, this will break the query string.